# how to sort php multidimensional array by other array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array with IDs that looks like

```
 $order_ids = array(8,9,10,4,7);
```

and another multidimensional array that looks like

```
 array(
       0  => array(
                   0 => 4, // order id
                   1 => 23 // item_id
                   2 => 1 // qty
       ),
  1  => array(
                   0 => 9, // order id
                   1 => 66 // item_id
                   2 => 4 // qty
       ),
  2  => array(
                  0 => 8, // order id
                   1 => 17 // item_id
                   2 => 3 // qty
       ),
 )
```

i tried

```
 $keys = array_flip($order_ids);

 usort($multiarray, function($a, $b) use($keys)
 {
     return $keys[$a] - $keys[$b[0];
 });
```

The order_ids of the 2nd array correspond to the values in the first array. What I need to do is sort the 2nd array by the order_ids  in the order they are in the 1st array.

Comment: What ahve you tried and where were you stuck? There are plenty of examples for similar problems both on and off the site, they should've gotten you at least halfway to a solution.

Comment: please show us your best attempt at solving your issue, you might be closer than you think! Suggested reading [ask].

Comment: You use `['id']`, but the array you're trying to sort is not associative. You have marked the `0` index as the one with the order id, so you should try `[0]` instead. P.S. This should be giving you Undefined index notices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cycle through the records in `$arr` and store them in the order set by `$order_ids` - result in `$newArr`:

```
<?php
$order_ids = array(8,9,10,4,7);

$arr = [
    [4, 23, 1],
    [9, 66, 4],
    [8, 17, 3],
];

foreach($order_ids as $id) {
    foreach($arr as $record) {
        if($record[0] == $id) {
            $newArr[] = $record;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/YM6Ge)